# WebGL Rendering Optimization - Matrices

Tags: javascript, matrix, optimization, webgl, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to use WebGL to render hundreds of thousands of textures in the most efficient way possible.

Currently I've reached a quite decent flow having around 20K artifacts being rendered at 100fps+. Still not happy enough, I've made a chrome profiling to check possible bottlenecks on the code and I've saw that my matrix rotation calculations are taking a big piece of the cake:

[image: rotate method and performance weight]

And the correspondent Bottom-Up trace:

[image: Bottom-up trace]

Do you have any idea of what type of optimizations can be executed here? It seems that somehow the "rotate" operation is taking in particular an abnormal amount of resources.

Matrix4 Code: https://github.com/scarlettgamestudio/scarlett-framework/blob/feature/render_optimizations/src/math/matrix4.js

SpriteBatch: https://github.com/scarlettgamestudio/scarlett-framework/blob/feature/render_optimizations/src/core/spriteBatch.js

TextureShader: https://github.com/scarlettgamestudio/scarlett-framework/blob/feature/render_optimizations/src/shaders/textureShader.shader.js

Many thanks.

Comment: This would probably be better asked in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: How do you get 200+ fps while you're bound to vsync with request animation frame?

Comment: @LJᛃ the vsync adapts to the monitor refresh rate, since my monitor is 144hz, the framerate can go up to that number.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from saving a few multiplications and shortening paths in that code there isn't anything left from a micro-optimization point of view, assuming you're already using typed arrays for all your values(`matrix`, `axis`).

Depending on your application logic you have the following options though:

- Only rotate what's actually visible using an appropriate culling method
- Assuming you're not vertex bound, offload rotation to the GPU by doing it in the vertex shader
- Assuming you're rotating by the same angle, store the rotation matrix instead of reconstructing it

Also note that rendering is async from the main thread and thus not considered in the trace, there very well might be ways to improve performance by optimizing your rendering code as well.

Since I read "sprites" in the trace you provided I'd go with offloading the rotation to the GPU as first attempt.

Comment: [typedarrays appear to be slower than native javascript arrays](http://greggman.github.io/webgl-matrix-benchmarks/matrix_benchmark.html) .  In that example "TDLMath" and "twgl-native" are using javascript arrays where as "twgl" and "TDLFast" are using typedarrays. On top of that [V8 is missing some basic optimizations that SpiderMonkey is not](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=6363) but in any case on both native is faster than typedarrays. I don't know if that's because they haven't been fully optimized or if just the conversion float->double->float is kiling perf.

Comment: Thanks for the points.. I'm not vertex bound, using offload rotation is something I'll definitely try next.. Regarding your last point (storing the rotation matrix), it's useful for a real case scenario, right now I'm doing the worst case scenario by modifying all object properties (which require a total recalculation). For more code, this is the spritebatch I'm developing: https://github.com/scarlettgamestudio/scarlett-framework/blob/feature/render_optimizations/src/core/spriteBatch.js

Comment: @gman thanks for pointing that out, lets hope for things to get better or SIMD.js to take over ;)